# Production deployable, scalable and managed solution from Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I explored most of the options available in Heroku and none of them has a feasible and managed plan for Django based eCommerce web application. We basically don't want to manage the infrastructure and configurations, but would like to focus on coding and deploy it on a managed solution that is feasible to us.

Currently we have the following software stack on a development server and we would like to find a Heroku managed solution, yet scalable and production deployable.

1. Linux OS
2. Postgres
3. Python 3.10
4. Django latest ( with and without REST APIs)
5. Vue.js
6. Gunicorn
7. Nginx
8. Let's Encrypt or any SSL
9. Redis
10. Celery
11. Github
12. Jenkins CI/CD (the code is automatically deployed on the development server by running a Jenkins job)
13. Integrated API: Stripe, Twilio, Google and etc.

I would appreciate it if any one is using a managed server plan either from Heroku or Digital ocean so that we would like to explore that option and see if it is feasible to us. Sorry for missing my question earlier.

Best regards

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my question now. Could you check it and let me know if you have any suggestion?